# Terraform template within a templatefile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to use a template within a templatefile in terraform? Let's say I have repetitive blocks within a template

template.tmpl:-

```
{ 
   A1,
   A2,
   A3
}
```

Now assuming element A can be saved as another template, which could then be reused in my original template. Giving an example in pseduo code.

A.tmpl

```
{
 <some code here>
}
```

template.tmpl

```
{ 
   template(A, A1params)
   template(A, A2params)
   template(A, A3params)
}
```

Is this possible in terraform?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you share a slightly more realistic example? It's quite possible there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm generating a cloudwatch dashboard json body as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888707/terraform-json-generation. The code has lot of repetition and that's what prompted this question.